# Brushless motor makes knocking noise when running in reverse

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I bought [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/154046292194) off of ebay, to go into my Razor MX500 dirtbike and connected it to a 72V 20AH lifepo4 battery. After fitting the motor, it was running nice and smooth but I noticed that it was driving backwards. With no option to flip the motor around (I need the shaft on the right hand side due to the location of the chain), I began tinkering with ways to reverse the motor.

The first way I tried was to use a "reverse" switch option coming off the ESC and simply jump it, which caused the motor to indeed spin in reverse, but it was limited to around 1/3 the speed of the un-reversed motor.

The second thing I tried was swapping the yellow/blue wires in both the hall sensor (small wires) and the connecting terminals (big wires.) This paired yellow to blue, blue to yellow. It did switch the direction the motor turned, but there's a clunking noise sounding like the motor is resisting being turned this way. It actually blew a 30A inline fuse I had connected.

Does anybody know the proper way to reverse the direction of the motor? Is it possible it's not brushless after all?

I can provide pictures if that would help.

Comment: Almost always, you can not just turn the clock/position sensor backward. The position sensor has to know the rotor absolute angle, and then the controller generates corresponding EMF to spin the rotor. If the BLDC does not take reverse, then use mechanical arrangement.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJd-upxFemA&ab_channel=MegaPowerServices it's similar box, so probably the same procedure.

Comment: It looks like he swaps the same as me on the connector box, blue and yellow, but he swaps green and yellow for hall sensors. I will try this and report back with the results.